# Component updates its content only after refresh, how to make it update without refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, react-context

User menu

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";

import { getAuth, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import { AuthDataContext } from "../../context/Auth-Context";
export default function UserMenu(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthDataContext);

  const logOut = function () {
    const auth = getAuth();
    signOut(auth).catch((err) => console.error(err));
    navigate("../../night-owl");
  };

  console.log(user);

  return (
    <div className={`UserMenu ${props.activeMenu === false ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
      <div className="UserMenu__triangle"></div>
      <div className="UserMenu__options">
        <NavLink
          to="/night-owl/auth/account"
          className={`${!user ? "hidden" : ""}`}
        >
          profile
        </NavLink>

        <NavLink
          className={`UserMenu__options__log-in ${user ? "hidden" : ""}`}
          to="/night-owl/auth/log-in"
        >
          log in
        </NavLink>
        <span
          onClick={logOut}
          className={`UserMenu__options__log-out ${!user ? "hidden" : ""}`}
        >
          log out
        </span>
        {!user && <NavLink to="auth/sign-up">register</NavLink>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Authentication Context

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  EmailAuthCredential,
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";

export const AuthDataContext = createContext(null);

export default function AuthContext({ children }) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      return setUser(user);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });

  return (
    <AuthDataContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthDataContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I need to render NavLinks and span based on this conditional rendering, but it works only after refresh, I need it to refresh immediately after user is changed.

In the code below for ex., the condition works, like in others too, but the problem is it works only after refresh.

```
<NavLink
  className={`UserMenu__options__log-in ${user ? "hidden" : ""}`}
  to="/night-owl/auth/log-in"
>
```

Maybe I need to use states, to save user in a state here in the component, but I don't want another variable here.

Comment: Wouldn’t you need to set the user back to null in `onAuthStateChanged` if it didn’t receive a user?

Comment: Show us the whole component that `NavLink` is contained within. Is there any memorization, via `useMemo` or `React.memo()`?

Comment: @DaveNewton, your suggestion was right, if the user is logged out it should set the user state to null, which is the conditions of rendering links (hide or show them depending on the boolean value of the user), the problem was instead of setting the user to null I returned just the null value.